# How to add a edit to-do list item feature?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive been studying javascript and following along on this online tutorial for a to-do list.  I switched up and added a few of my own features, but I am not sure how would go about adding a feature where I can edit a individual list item?

I started off creating a function editTodo(key), I know I would have to append my new text to the old list text?  If someone could give me a hint or guide me in the right direction?

```js
//array that holds todo list items
let listItems = [];


//Function will create a new list item based on whatever the input value
//was entered in the text input
function addItem (text) {
    const todo = {
        text,              //whatever user types in
        checked: false,   //boolean which lets us know if a task been marked complete
        id: Date.now(),    //unique identifier for item
    };
//it is then pushed onto the listItems array
    listItems.push(todo);
    renderTodo(todo);
}


function checkDone(key) {
    //findIndex is an array method that returns position of an element in array
    const index = listItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
    //locates the todo item in the listItems array and set its checked property
    //to opposite. 'true' will become 'false'
    listItems[index].checked = !listItems[index].checked;
    renderTodo(listItems[index]);
}

function deleteTodo(key) {
    //find todo object in the listItems array
    const index = listItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
    //create a new object with properties of the current list item
    //delete property set to true
    const todo = {
        deleted: true,
        ...listItems[index]
    };

    //remove the list item from the array by filtering it out
    listItems = listItems.filter(item => item.id !== Number(key));
    renderTodo(todo);
}

//edits list item
function editTodo(key) {
    //find todo object in the listItems array
    const index = listItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key)); 


}


//selects form element
const form = document.querySelector('.js-form');
const addGoal = document.getElementById('addBtn');
//adds a submit event listener
    function selectForm(event) {

    //prevent page refresh on form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    //select the text input
    const input = document.querySelector('.js-todo-input');
    //gets value of the input and removes whitespace beginning/end of string
    //we then save that to new variable -> text
    const text = input.value.trim();
    //checks whether 2 operands are not equal, returning true or false (boolean)
    //if input value is not equal to blank, add user input
    if (text !== '') {
        addItem(text);
        input.value = '';    //value of text input is cleared by setting it to empty
        input.focus();       //focused so user can add many items to list witout focusing the input
    }

};

addGoal.addEventListener('click', selectForm, false);
form.addEventListener('submit', selectForm, false);


function renderTodo(todo) {
    //saves local storage items, convert listItems array to JSON string
    localStorage.setItem('listItemsRef', JSON.stringify(listItems));
    //selects the first element with a class of 'js-to'list'
    const list = document.querySelector('.js-todo-list');
    //selects current todo (refer to top) list item in DOM
    const item = document.querySelector(`[data-key='${todo.id}']`);

    //refer to function deleteTodo(key)
    if (todo.deleted) {
        //remove item from DOM
        item.remove();
        return
    }

    //use the ternary operator to check if 'todo.checked' is true
    //if true, assigns 'done' to checkMarked. if not, assigns empty string
    const checkMarked = todo.checked ? 'done' : '';
    //creates list 'li' item and assigns it to 'goal'
    const goal = document.createElement('li');
    //sets the class attribute
    goal.setAttribute('class', `todo-item ${checkMarked}`);
    //sets the data-key attribute to the id of the todo
    goal.setAttribute('data-key', todo.id);
    //sets the contents of the list item 'li'
    goal.innerHTML = `
    <input id="${todo.id}" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="${todo.id}" class="tick js-tick"></label>
    <span>${todo.text}</span>
    <button class="edit-todo js-edit-todo"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></button>
    <button class="delete-todo js-delete-todo">X</button>
    `;

    //if item already exists in the DOM
    if (item) {
        //replace it
        list.replaceChild(goal, item);
    }else {
        //otherwise if it doesnt (new list items) add at the end of the list
    list.append(goal);
    }
}



    //selects entire list
    const list = document.querySelector('.js-todo-list');
    //adds click event listener to the list and its children
    list.addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('js-tick')) {
            const itemKey = event.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
            checkDone(itemKey);
        }

        //add this 'if block
        if (event.target.classList.contains('js-delete-todo')) {
            const itemKey = event.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
            deleteTodo(itemKey);
        }
    })
  
//render any existing listItem when page is loaded

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const ref = localStorage.getItem('listItemsRef');
    if (ref) {
        listItems = JSON.parse(ref);
        listItems.forEach(t => {
            renderTodo(t);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.4;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    height: 90vh;
    margin-top: 20vh;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  .app-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 80px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  
  
  .todo-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .todo-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .todo-item span {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  .done span {
    background-color:#0099e5;
    color:#fff;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
  }

  #addBtn {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#0099e5;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    margin-left:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  #addBtn:hover {
    background-color:#0078b4;
  }
  
  .tick {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .tick::before {
    content: '✓';
    font-size: 20px;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .done .tick::before {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  .delete-todo {
    border: none;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius:20px;
  }

  .edit-todo {
    border: none;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:green;
    color:#fff;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius:20px;
  }

  .empty-warning {
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    display:none;
  }

  .todo-list:empty {
    display:none;
  }

  .todo-list:empty + .empty-warning {
    display:flex;
  }

  .empty-warning-title {
    margin-top:15px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
  }
  
  
  form {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
  
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/67e5409c20.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="app-title">To Do List</h1>
        
        <form class="js-form">
          <input autofocus type="text" aria-label="Enter a new todo item" placeholder="Ex - Walk the dog" class="js-todo-input">
          <input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add"> 
        </form>
        
        <ul class="todo-list js-todo-list"></ul>
        <div class="empty-warning">
          <h2 class="empty-warning-title">Add your first goal</h2>
       </div>
      </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the edit feature to the event handler for click events on the list:

**Figure I**

```
if (event.target.matches('.edit-todo') && event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
  const text = event.target.previousElementSibling;
  text.toggleAttribute('contenteditable');
  if (text.contenteditable) {
    text.focus();
  }
}
```

Basically, when the user clicks an edit button the `contenteditable` attribute is toggled (`true`/`false`) on the `<span>` that sits right before the button (hence `.previousElementSibling`).

I also added 2 CSS rulesets as well:

**Figure II**

```
.fa-pencil { pointer-events: none }
[contenteditable] { outline: 3px inset blue }
```

For some reason my mouse cannot click font-awesome icons, I have no idea why. So I disabled click events on the edit icon in order to click the edit button. Others might have the same problem as I do -- I'm 99% sure there's no harm in keeping that ruleset since it just makes the edit button 100% the origin element on the event chain. The second ruleset is a visual cue to the user that the `<span>` is editable.

```js
let listItems = [];

function addItem(text) {
  const todo = {
    text,
    checked: false,
    id: Date.now(),
  };
  listItems.push(todo);
  renderTodo(todo);
}

function checkDone(key) {
  const index = listItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
  listItems[index].checked = !listItems[index].checked;
  renderTodo(listItems[index]);
}

function deleteTodo(key) {
  const index = listItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
  const todo = {
    deleted: true,
    ...listItems[index]
  };

  listItems = listItems.filter(item => item.id !== Number(key));
  renderTodo(todo);
}

function editTodo(key) {
  const index = listItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
}

const form = document.querySelector('.js-form');
const addGoal = document.getElementById('addBtn');

function selectForm(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  const input = document.querySelector('.js-todo-input');
  const text = input.value.trim();
  if (text !== '') {
    addItem(text);
    input.value = '';
    input.focus();
  }
};

addGoal.addEventListener('click', selectForm, false);
form.addEventListener('submit', selectForm, false);

function renderTodo(todo) {
  // localStorage.setItem('listItemsRef', JSON.stringify(listItems));
  const list = document.querySelector('.js-todo-list');
  const item = document.querySelector(`[data-key='${todo.id}']`);

  if (todo.deleted) {
    item.remove();
    return
  }

  const checkMarked = todo.checked ? 'done' : '';
  const goal = document.createElement('li');
  goal.setAttribute('class', `todo-item ${checkMarked}`);
  goal.setAttribute('data-key', todo.id);
  goal.innerHTML = `
    <input id="${todo.id}" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="${todo.id}" class="tick js-tick"></label>
    <span>${todo.text}</span>
    <button class="edit-todo js-edit-todo"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></button>
    <button class="delete-todo js-delete-todo">X</button>
    `;

  if (item) {
    list.replaceChild(goal, item);
  } else {
    list.append(goal);
  }
}

const list = document.querySelector('.js-todo-list');
list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('js-tick')) {
    const itemKey = event.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
    checkDone(itemKey);
  }

  if (event.target.classList.contains('js-delete-todo')) {
    const itemKey = event.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
    deleteTodo(itemKey);
  }

  if (event.target.matches('.edit-todo') && event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    const text = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    text.toggleAttribute('contenteditable');
    if (text.contenteditable) {
      text.focus();
    }
  }
})

/*
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ref = localStorage.getItem('listItemsRef');
  if (ref) {
    listItems = JSON.parse(ref);
    listItems.forEach(t => {
      renderTodo(t);
    });
  }
});*/
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
  height: 90vh;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.app-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 80px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.todo-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.todo-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.todo-item span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.done span {
  background-color: #0099e5;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

#addBtn {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0099e5;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #0078b4;
}

.tick {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tick::before {
  content: '✓';
  font-size: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.done .tick::before {
  display: inline;
}

.delete-todo {
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.edit-todo {
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.empty-warning {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
}

.todo-list:empty {
  display: none;
}

.todo-list:empty+.empty-warning {
  display: flex;
}

.empty-warning-title {
  margin-top: 15px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
}

.fa-pencil {
  pointer-events: none
}

[contenteditable] {
  outline: 3px inset blue
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/67e5409c20.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="app-title">To Do List</h1>

    <form class="js-form">
      <input autofocus type="text" aria-label="Enter a new todo item" placeholder="Ex - Walk the dog" class="js-todo-input">
      <input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add">
    </form>

    <ul class="todo-list js-todo-list"></ul>
    <div class="empty-warning">
      <h2 class="empty-warning-title">Add your first goal</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for help!, One thing I'm noticing though is if you check off a list item that you edited, the list item will go back to its previous value? I'm trying to figure out why?

Comment: My guess is because the new value isn't getting stored in local storage?

Comment: Yep, I had to disable that feature because SO blocks `localStorage` when using a Snippet,  so there'd be error messages. Just uncomment those lines and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for that info, unfortunately the problem still persists even when I un-comment the lines.

Comment: I took a look. The `localstorage` routine is overtly complicated. There's a lot of parts -- the more parts you got the more you'll be prone to errors. You can have one function to save everything and smaller function to load the saved data. To fix that, is beyond the scope of the question. You should start another question for `localStorage` problems.